# How to set to an instance of an object as below code?

Tags: c#, selenium, variables, webdriver, set

I want your help to my problem, Please:
From my test class, I try run my test code:

```
[setUp]
public void setup()
{
BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
}
```

But, it failed, because it didn’t initialized the “driver” variable.

(I got msg: system.nullReferenceException: The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser)

Below code of InitBrowser() function as I copied from  [http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/browser-factory-or-webdriver-factory/](http://browser%20factory-%20tools%20QA)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _AutomationTests.WrapperFactory
{
   public class BrowserFactory
   {
       private static readonly IDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
        private static IWebDriver driver;

    public static IWebDriver Driver
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.");
            return driver;
        }
        private set
        {
            driver = value;
        }
    }

    public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
    {
        switch (browserName)
        {
            case "Firefox":
                if (Driver == null)
                {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    Drivers.Add("Firefox", Driver);
                }
                break;

            case "IE":
                if (Driver == null)
                {
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\PathTo\IEDriverServer");
                    Drivers.Add("IE", Driver);
                }
                break;

            case "Chrome":
                if (Driver == null)
                {
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();//@"C:\PathTo\CHDriverServer"
                    Drivers.Add("Chrome", Driver);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void LoadApplication(string url)
    {
        Driver.Url = url;
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
    }

    public static void CloseAllDrivers()
    {
        foreach (var key in Drivers.Keys)
        {
            Drivers[key].Close();
            Drivers[key].Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

}

thank alot!

Comment: Can you paste your current code (for the test and InitBrowser) into your question?

Comment: Yes. I use your first suggestion, and the above problem was solved. But now it failed on LoadApplication() function, "Driver.Url=url;", I got this error message: "Argument 'url' cannot be null." When the called statment is:             BrowserFactory.LoadApplication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["https://www.google.co.il/webhp?tab=ow&authuser=0&ei=Tnk2WZmXFMP7-AGGhIvwBQ&ved=0EKkuCAQoAQ"]);
Can you help me with that too?

Comment: By the way, I found same Q in this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104389/selenium-webdriver-the-webdriver-browser-instance-was-not-initialized-when-usin)

Comment: Is there a config (e.g. app.config) file in your project? If so, please include the contents of that file in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code.

You should change each of these lines:

`if (Driver == null)`

to this:

`if (driver == null)`

Another option is to change the get from:

```
    get
    {
        if (driver == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.");
        return driver;
    }
```

to:

```
    get
    {
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: This is correct solution, I took same code as OP did and knew these is something wrong but didn't know which part to fix exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Mar, try to paste the full source code of your project. Where are those C# classes of ChromeDriver(), FirefoxDriver(),InternetExplorerDriver() in project. Have you coded them upfront ?
Here **IWebDriver** Driver is a property

Null check is not required in getter of public static IWebDriver Driver

```
public BrowserFactory()
        {
            Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {

                return driver;
            }
            private set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }
```

Set the property of IWebDriver Driver to an instance while the class is loaded in a static initializer or Constructor like :

Even before the driver could be initialized the get property is called which evalutates the null check to true & hence throwing exception.

Questions to be asked to yourself:

1. Have you added library files for Firefox,Chrome & IE ??
2. Is it a part of your project configuration file ?
3. If not added the best way to add is using Nuget Package manager in visual studio
   4.Those references should be part of your project. Let me post a screenshot of a similar project I tried 
   [image: References to library files]
   5.See the pic of Nuget Package Manager 
   [image: Click Manage Nuget Packages]
   6.Click Manage Nuget Packages, browse for Available Packages
   7.[image: Install Nuget Package]
4. Finally, you are not setting a new instance of driver

[pre]

```
{
    class Driver
    {
        public enum Browser
        {
            chrome,
            firefox,
            ie,
        }
        public IWebDriver getDriver(string browser_type)
        {
            Browser parsed_browser_type; IWebDriver driver=null;
            bool passed_type = browser_type != null ? true : false;
            if (passed_type)
            {
                Enum.TryParse(browser_type, out parsed_browser_type);

                switch (browser_type.ToLower())
                {

                    case "chrome":
                       driver= new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions { Proxy = null });
                        break;
                    case "firefox":
                       driver= new FirefoxDriver();
                        break;
                    case "ie":
                        driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(new InternetExplorerOptions { Proxy = null });
                        break;
                    default:
                    case "":
                       throw new Exception("Browser cannot be null");
                }
            }
            return driver;
        }
    }
}
```

[/pre]